# Crypto++ Lib in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, crypto++

I am using the `Crypto++` library for using various encryption algorithms.

I know the library is written using c++ as the language, but I want to use the SAME library in C#.  How can I convert this library code to c#?

The reason I want to do this is to make it easier to compare between this library and the other C# libraries in my project.

I am using VISUAL STUDIO 2010.

Comment: [Bouncy Castle ](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) do a C# crypto library, which will duplicate many of the same or simlar library methods.

Comment: i saw bouncy castle.. they support various algos but i cant find how to implement them in c# @rossum

Comment: *"My project requires use of this library but i need it in c# as i have other algorithms in C# so comparing becomes easy..."* - What is your goal, or what are you trying to do? Crypto++ proper as a managed DLL for C# may not be attainable or advisable, but you may be able to do other things, like benchmark algorithms.

Comment: I refactored the question to make it read more smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this library yet but if it is a normal .dll you can use "DllImport" like

```
[DllImport("cryptoplusplus.dll")]
public static extern int ExportToCall(int argument);
```

However if it is just C++, you would have to compile an assembly first.

Comment: Crypto++ is a C++ library, not a C library. The DLL is a FIPS DLL, so it only provides the core FIPS algorithms, The library does not provide C language bindings, so `ExportToCall` is wishful thinking.